# Excluded from meetings

Tags: meetings

I am a lead developer in a business unit, there are 2 other lead developers that are invited to project meetings with the head of department, where they get updates and as asked for their input.

I am excluded from these meetings. I feel that it is unprofessional not to invite me to these meetings, we are all working on the same projects, and it undermines my position.

all 3 of us are directly working on the projects being discussed and we are all equally effected by what is decided at the meetings

How can i raise this with the head of department ?

Comment: what is you position in the projects which are carried out?

Comment: Possibly the projects they are discussing are not directly related to you? In that case I would not complain being excluded from meetings that could have been emails as far as I was concerned

Comment: Have you asked to be included?  If so, what was the reply?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Indeed. The reason for the exclusion is critical information. If OP is excluded because they're a woman, the answer would be radically different than if they were excluded because their projects are only being tangentially referred to at the end of meetings about other things.

Comment: It seems to me that we don't have enough information to properly help you.  The information that is present is pretty one-sided.  Are you all on different teams?  If not, maybe they have your team covered.  Seems hard to believe that management sees equal impact, if you are not present.  You mention unprofessional, "raising issues", exclusion, and "undermining your position."  If you fear for your position, perhaps a better course would be to rebuild your position, instead of asking it to be administratively enforced (by one who already didn't do that).

Comment: Assuming you're on good standing with these other teammates, have you asked them about the meetings? Perhaps they can include you on the meetings

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do is talk to the head of your department.  Tell him or her exactly what you posted, but dont be confrontational.  Simply mention that you would like to be included in the meetings.  That you would benefit from the updates and your input is valuable.  *Do not* ask why you were excluded, or that you feel it is unprofessional.

Perhaps it is as simple as he/she thinks you are too busy to attend, or he/she thought you werent interested.

If he/she says no, then you could consider asking for the reason for the exclusion.  No matter what your initial reaction to that reason is, take  time to consider what was said.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in this position except in a sort of head of department position. There was no excluding going on. It was that the other team member did not have to be involved in the discussion on particular aspects of the project. Also, there were occasionally times where I wanted one or more team members to grow. Therefore, I would have them stand in for me to upper management. There wasn’t any planned or implied exclusion. The employee like you came to me and still wasn’t happy when I explained my decision. Though at least I gave them an outlet to explain myself.

There are also times that a team member is out and I still hold meetings regardless. I am not going to stop a meeting because someone is on vacation and business must go on.

That all being said, discuss your concerns calmly. I suspect the motivations are innocent and you will have to live with the decision to be excluded if that is what the Department Head wants.

Answer (score 0):

Raising issue with the head of department may help or may not help, but surely it will come back to you in course of coming period.

In short this is sign to look for alternatives, just move ahead.